# Find multiple ocurrences of the same character using REGEXP_LIKE in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle10g

I have the following situation: I have an email  databases of people who want to receive promotional emails about the company, stuff like flash sales, new product advertisement and etc. But for some time now, people have been registering bogus email addresses like `aaa@aaa.aa`. I'm currently working on a way to cleanse this table and my main issue so far has been finding the correct `REGEXP_LIKE` pattern to help me.

I've tried this `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (email_address, '(\w){3,}')` but that's no good. It found emails like `john@doe.com`. I've tried searching for a way to do this in oracle but so far no good.

Can anyone assist me ?

Comment: Did you bother to read the docs? They have this very same situation as an example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#sthref1001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the following patterns:

```
'(\w)\1{2,}'
'((\w)+)\1+'
```

The first Pattern will detect sequences of 3 or more of the same character. For example aaa or bbb.  The second pattern will detect sequences of 2 or more repeating patterns of characters, such as aa, bbb, abab, or 123123, etc.

This works by using the \1 which is a back reference to the 1st pattern surrounded by parenthesis.  In the first pattern the back reference refers to a pattern of exactly one character.  In the second pattern, the back reference refers to a batter of 1 or more characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that you exxplained this, it makes a lot of sense and it works perfectly!